# Embedding a Youtube Video: Custom Javascript Actions on Thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm working on embedding a youtube video using a custom javascript thumbnail. If done correctly, the page should load with a custom thumbnail and on-click should load an iframe youtube video and automatically begin playing.

I'm working with this tutorial for refrence:
[A More Efficient Method for Embedding YouTube Videos](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

I am a beginning web developer and I am getting some buggy results. I've managed to get a custom thumbnail to load and the corresponding video to play automatically when the user clicks the thumbnail, but the page loads with a small visible file thumbnail in the top left corner of the video thumbnail.

Can anybody find any errors with the html or java? I think I have the css portion correct but I will add that in too for refrence.

HTML

```html
<div class="youtube-container">
        <div class="youtube-player" id="yo" data-id="9jkx03pnMtg">
            <div> 
                <img class="youtube-thumb" src="img/yo_thumbnail.png">
            <div class="play-button"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script

```js
<script>
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();

function labnolThumb(id) {
    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?autoplay=1");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
</script>
```

CSS

```css
.youtube-container { display: block; margin: 20px auto; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; }
.youtube-player { display: block; width: 100%; /* assuming that the video has a 16:9 ratio */ padding-bottom: 56.25%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; display: block; }
img.youtube-thumb { bottom: 0; display: block; left: 0; margin: auto; max-width: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; height: auto }
div.play-button { height: 72px; width: 72px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -36px; margin-top: -36px; position: absolute; background: url("http://i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat; }
#youtube-iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the `img` tag in your html. That's what you're seeing in the corner of the video thumbnail.

```html
<img class="youtube-thumb" src="img/yo_thumbnail.png">
```

It's automatically being added by the javascript:

```js
function labnolThumb(id) {
    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}
```